# How Do I Disable Spring Dev-Tools esp: LiveReloadConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This Spring App is failing because of *LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$LiveReloadConfiguration.class*. This is a Spring dev-tools class and I'd like to remove dev-tools so that I can continue development. I tried both of these, to no avail.

1. removing the dev-tools:

> ```
> <!--      <dependency>-->
> <!--          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
> <!--          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>-->
> <!--          <scope>runtime</scope>-->
> <!--          <optional>true</optional>-->
> <!--      </dependency>-->
> ```

2. adding this to the *application.properties*.

   *spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false*

How can I disable this class?

Exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'optionalLiveReloadServer' defined in class
> path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$LiveReloadConfiguration.class]:
> Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name
> 'restart'

Comment: are you using `maven or gradle` ? if you are using maven have you run `mvn clean install` or for gradle `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` after commenting out the dependency?

Comment: @Rishal recall doing exactly that (mvn clean install) and still having the problem. I ended up recreating it from scratch without the dev-tools and it works. When I have time I'll verify your suggestion.